# Oracle PL SQL Select query with join two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in Oracle, `EmployeeMaster` and `EmployeeMarks`.

I want to write a SQL query to get results like shown in this screenshot:

[image: Table Structure and Ressult]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Please include your data as _text_ (indented by four spaces), not as image links.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values, use `JOIN`:

```
select
    e.employeename,
    m.marks
from employee_master e
join employee_marks m on e.id = m.employeemasterid;
```

Always use modern explicit `JOIN` syntax.

The cell merging shouldn't be done in SQL as SQL is not the suitable tool for this.
Do this in application code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can't we do column merge using sql query ?

Comment: Question is not whether we can or not, it's whether we should. As I said, do not do this in SQL. It'll be ugly, fragile and incomprehensible code

Answer (score 0):

```
select
e.employeename,
m.employeemasterid As EmpID,
sum(m.marks) As marks
```

from employee_master e
      Inner join employee_marks m 
            on e.id = m.employeemasterid

```
        Group By e.employeename, m.employeemasterid;
```